# mpdf not generating pdf if data is larger

Tags: php, mpf

I'm trying to generate a labels for the members. It comes with two things Address and Name. I'm using mpdf to generate pdf. I don't know why mpdf is not generating pdf for twenty second data on-wards.

So, i tried to check it by replacing same data on 21st data on-wards. and again the result is same. I tried like below to create the problem I'm facing.

change for loop increment number from 21 to 22 and that's all...! Mpdf stops working. why only for 21st data it will generate pdf ? I Don't know.

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$style= "<style>html,body{height:297mm;width:210mm;padding: 8mm 4mm 8mm 4mm}   p{font-size:14px;} div{overflow:hidden;width:65mm;height:38mm; float:left;border:1px solid;margin:0;padding:-2 0 -2 5px;} </style>";
for ($x = 0; $x < 21; $x++) {
    $data .= "<div style='page-break-inside:avoid;padding:5px;'><p>ANAND S.N.</p><P>  #54, M/S, RAJATHA ENTREPRISE V.T.STREET, SARJAPURA POST
                BENGALURU RURAL, ANEKAL, 562125</P></div>"; 
} 

$data_print = $style.'<p>'.$data.'</p>';

echo $data_print;
$mpdf = new mPDF();
// $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

$mpdf->WriteHTML($data_print);
$mpdf->Output('mpdf.pdf','D');
```

I have more then twenty thousand records list and I need to take print on this format. So, will mpdf work or Do i need to go for any other alternatives.

Comment: What would happen if you didn't restrict the height of the body?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I'm Not getting anything.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Is it a bug or mpdf cannot do it.

Comment: I doubt that, but perhaps going from HTML to PDF is not the best choice here, after all you have the data in PHP, why not convert it directly to PDF? For your application something like [FPDF](https://www.fpdf.org) could be more suitable. (certificate of site is invalid, but site is working normally, ignore the warnings, they are a bit over the top for this situation)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware without using any pdf converter how to generate pdf in php. tell me more about it. then ill go for FPDF

Comment: Visit [FPDF](https://www.fpdf.org), read the tutorials, have a look at all the example scripts and the manual. It's all there.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware i thought without using FPDF. its ok

Comment: Ah, ok, well, that is possible, but the PDF script is not easy. Why would you dive into that if you have a library that does it for you? You can [find out more about PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF).

Answer (score 0):

For others who are getting same problem. once check if you gave
ob_start();
after
include('vendor_pdf/vendor/autoload.php');
followed by your php code
and then

```
$content = ob_get_clean(); // get content of the buffer and clean the buffer
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
$mpdf->Output();
```